# OpenShift - Update Python and Install PIP in a Rails app

Tags: python, command-line, pip, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I have created my Rails app on OpenShift. It uses Python and a package installed from PIP. How do I upgrade to a newer Python version (currently it is 2.6) ?

Visible cartridges:

```
user@debian:~$ rhc cartridges
jbossas-7                JBoss Application Server 7              web
jboss-dv-6.1.0 (!)       JBoss Data Virtualization 6             web
jbosseap-6 (*)           JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6 web
jboss-unified-push-1 (!) JBoss Unified Push Server 1.0.0.Beta1   web
jboss-unified-push-2 (!) JBoss Unified Push Server 1.0.0.Beta2   web
jenkins-1                Jenkins Server                          web
nodejs-0.10              Node.js 0.10                            web
perl-5.10                Perl 5.10                               web
php-5.3                  PHP 5.3                                 web
php-5.4                  PHP 5.4                                 web
zend-6.1                 PHP 5.4 with Zend Server 6.1            web
python-2.6               Python 2.6                              web
python-2.7               Python 2.7                              web
python-3.3               Python 3.3                              web
ruby-1.8                 Ruby 1.8                                web
ruby-1.9                 Ruby 1.9                                web
ruby-2.0                 Ruby 2.0                                web
jbossews-1.0             Tomcat 6 (JBoss EWS 1.0)                web
jbossews-2.0             Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)                web
jboss-vertx-2.1 (!)      Vert.x 2.1                              web
jboss-wildfly-8 (!)      WildFly Application Server 8.2.1.Final  web
jboss-wildfly-9 (!)      WildFly Application Server 9            web
diy-0.1                  Do-It-Yourself 0.1                      web
cron-1.4                 Cron 1.4                                addon
jenkins-client-1         Jenkins Client                          addon
mongodb-2.4              MongoDB 2.4                             addon
mysql-5.1                MySQL 5.1                               addon
mysql-5.5                MySQL 5.5                               addon
phpmyadmin-4             phpMyAdmin 4.0                          addon
postgresql-8.4           PostgreSQL 8.4                          addon
postgresql-9.2           PostgreSQL 9.2                          addon
rockmongo-1.1            RockMongo 1.1                           addon
switchyard-0             SwitchYard 0.8.0                        addon
haproxy-1.4              Web Load Balancer                       addon

Note: Web cartridges can only be added to new applications.

(*) denotes a cartridge with additional usage costs.

(!) denotes a cartridge that will not receive automatic security updates.
```

And then trying to install a newer Python ...

```
user@debian:~$ rhc add-cartridge --app myappname python-3.3
Short Name       Full name
==========       =========
cron-1.4         Cron 1.4
jenkins-client-1 Jenkins Client
mongodb-2.4      MongoDB 2.4
mysql-5.1        MySQL 5.1
mysql-5.5        MySQL 5.5
phpmyadmin-4     phpMyAdmin 4.0
postgresql-8.4   PostgreSQL 8.4
postgresql-9.2   PostgreSQL 9.2
rockmongo-1.1    RockMongo 1.1
switchyard-0     SwitchYard 0.8.0
haproxy-1.4      Web Load Balancer

There are no cartridges that match 'python-3.3'.
```

If it's possible to install a newer version of Python, how do I install PIP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copied the lib to OpenShift, included it in the include path and executed it with py2.6! Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

There are no cartridges named python because when you try to add a cartridge to an existing app it will only show you the *compatible* cartridges. As noted by the `rhc cartridges` command:

```
Note: Web cartridges can only be added to *new* applications.
```

The best way for updating the python version is to create a new app and import the code from your old app.

1) Create a new app

```
$ rhc app create py33 python-3.3
```

2) Fetch the git url and add it as remote to your app

```
$ cd old_python_app
$ git remote add py33 ssh://py33-giturl
$ git push py33 master -f 
# Force push as the repo comes with default config files
```

As for `pip`, it comes preinstalled with openshift.

```
$ rhc ssh py33
$ pip --version
  pip 7.1.2 from /var/lib/openshift/.../python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages (python 3.3)
```